# Making EF Core properties backward compatible with Linq to Sql

Tags: asp.net-core, linq-to-sql, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc, npgsql

ASP. NET MVC 4.8 application uses DbLinq.
Database has tables where column and table names are same:

```
CREATE TABLE Product (
   Product CHAR(20) PRIMARY KEY );
```

Sql to Linq created entites with `Contents` property from them:

```
public class Product (
   public string Contents { get; set; }  
   }
```

Contents propery becomes part of published API used by third-party applications.

EF Core scaffold creates property `Product1` instead:

```
public class Product (
   public string Product1 { get; set; }  
   }
```

This breaks API specification.
How to make EF Core with API compatible ?
Is it possible to force it to generate Contents property as Sql to Linq ?
Or is it possible to add additional Contents property which actually gets and sets Product1 property values ?

Npgsql EF Core provider is used in ASP.NET Core MVC application.

Comment: Well, just rename the property and add mapping code. Scaffolding is nothing but a first help.

Comment: EF Core Power Tools allows you to rename navigations, if you continually scaffold

Comment: @GertArnold Scaffold is done continuosly in runtime using https://github.com/jdtcn/RuntimeEfCore .This should automated. How to use EF Core Power Tools or some other method in runtime, is there sample ?